# Error while sorting GridView column by clicking on header text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding a GridView in asp.net from data set. Here I am sorting a grid view by header text. My code is:

```
    public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
                return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
            }
            set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
        }

      protected void gridLeaveRequest_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

            if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                SortGridView(sortExpression, "DESCENDING");
            }
            else
            {
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                SortGridView(sortExpression, "ASCENDING");
            }
        }

        private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
        {
            dsLoginDetail = clsBLogic.GetLoginDetailByEmployeeNo(Convert.ToString(Session["LoginName"]));
            emoloyeeNo = dsLoginDetail.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeNo"].ToString();
            DataSet dsLeaveRequest = new DataSet();        
            dsLeaveRequest = clsBLogic.GetLeaveRequestByEmployeeNo(emoloyeeNo);        
            DataTable dt = dsLeaveRequest.Tables[0];
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
            gridLeaveRequest.DataSource = dv;
            gridLeaveRequest.DataBind();
        } 


 <asp:GridView ID="gridLeaveRequest" EmptyDataText="No Record Found..."  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gridLeaveRequest_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gridLeaveRequest_Sorting">

<asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose" ItemStyle-Width="40%" SortExpression="Purpose" >
</asp:BoundField>
```

When i click on purpose header of gridview, I get run time error `"Cannot find column PurposeDESCENDING."` on `dv.sort=sortExpression + direction;` 
    Any help?? thanks in advance

Comment: You need an space between sortExpression and direction:
dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + direction;

Comment: it didnot work.. the error is "Cannot find column Purpose DESCENDING."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `DESCENDING` with `DESC`

Change `ASCENDING` with `ASC`

Add space between `SortExpression` and `SortDirection`;

```
 dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + direction;
```